# android multiautocompletetextview: telling typed and selected items apart

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Is there any way, when using a MultiAutocompleteTextView, to tell apart the words that the user entirely typed and those that he rather selected from the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use onItemClickListener to see the ones he did not fully input.
I guess after you can remove them from your list of all selected items and have only the fully typed ones.

```
yourMultiView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        //here you can save the clicked elements
        Log.i("yourPackage",((TextView)arg1).getText().toString());
    }
});
```

That's how i managed to view the difference between the inputed values and the selected ones.

Comment: Yes, but the text I end up with in a multiautocompletetextview is a string of comma-separated tokens. Having to parse it all again at the end, filtering out what I have already saved as a selected item, looks rather inefficient to me. I was hoping for a more elegant solution...